# Perform average with the aggregated count value with group by clause

Tags: sql

Table is given as

```
Food ID  | Food Review
1        | good Review
1        | good Review
1        | Bad Review
2        | good Review
2        | Bad Review
3        | Good Review
```

and the Output expected is

```
Food ID   | Good Review | All Review | Acceptance score
1         | 2           | 3          | 2/3
```

Acceptance score will be calculated as good Review/All Review

Can anyone please help me with the query ?

Comment: Do you want `2/3` or `0.6666` as Acceptance score?

Comment: Do you only want foodid 1 in the result? What about 2 and 3? (Always have matching sample data and result.)

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: your Food Review for id 3 will be Good Review rather than  good Review it caused me alot problems;

Comment: @nikhilsugandh, do a case insensitive comparison. (But this reveals a design issue.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below

```
select 
    foodid, 
    count(case when FoodReview='good Review' then 1 end) as GoodReview,
    count(*) as allreview, (count(case when FoodReview='good Review' then 1 end)*1.0)/count(*) as Acceptancescore
from tablename
group by foodid
```

Comment: (count(case when FoodReview='good Review' then 1 end)*1.0)  i need to know why u have done * 1.0. query can work without * 1.0 also right? just a question. And thank you for your answer it helped a lot..

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
CREATE TABLE Tab
    ("a" int, "b" varchar2(11))
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO Tab ("a", "b")
         VALUES (1, 'good Review')
    INTO Tab ("a", "b")
         VALUES (1, 'good Review')
    INTO Tab ("a", "b")
         VALUES (1, 'Bad Review')
    INTO Tab ("a", "b")
         VALUES (2, 'good Review')
    INTO Tab ("a", "b")
         VALUES (2, 'Bad Review')
    INTO Tab ("a", "b")
         VALUES (3, 'good Review')
SELECT * FROM dual
;

select * from Tab;
select t1."a",count(t1."b")
from Tab t1
group by t1."a";

select m.*,m.GoodReview||'/'||all_review "ACCEPTANCE" from 
(select 
ta."a" ,
(select count(*) from Tab where 
"a"=ta."a"  and
"b"='good Review' group by "a")GoodReview,
(select count(*) from Tab where "a"=ta."a" group by ta."a") all_review
from 
Tab ta
group by ta."a") m ;

output:
1   2   3   2/3
2   1   2   1/2
3   1   1   1/1
```

Comment: Why didn't you keep the column names as specified in the question?

Comment: i did it  in sql fiddle it was showing some error  so have eto take them as they were from fiddle to my sql developer just changed the queries

Comment: No need to do group by in the correlated sub-queries.